# Got 404 when redirect every url to index

Tags: php

So, I've been trying to do the Wikipedia url thing! Like making the url readable. Tried every .htaccess code out thire and contacted the Hostinger customer services to help, and nothing works! I don't know why.

So, i move to use the PHP, and i got work great on test.php page that i use the test on, but when i move the code to index.php it doesn't.

So, the why i did it is having a page with php simple code: if url[2] has s include s.php, else include x.php. and it works great when i go to [www.website.com/test.php/s](http://www.website.com/test.php/s) it will open s.php

However,  when after i move the code to index.php and then i go to website.com/s i got an error as this page is not in the srver, but if i go to website.com/index.php/s it works.

So what do think i could fix it with? Or if there is any other why to do it. Thanks in advance ☺